# Samba crashes during multiple file transfer; need to restart samba to resume transfer. Win10 - Ubuntu 20.04.2 - Samba 4.11.6

Tags: 20.04, samba, crash, mdadm

Fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS + Samba 4.11.6 on an old HP PROLIANT MICROSERVER G1610T GEN8 which had run flawlessly for 6 years on Ubuntu 15.xx.
This w.e. I tried to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.xx but in the end I decided to start from scratch.
After a clean install I now run MDADM RAID-1 on two 1TB-HDDs, and have a 1TB + 2TB additional separate partition HDDs.   HP server is connected via eth cable to internal network.
All partitions, mounts, samba config etc.. had run smoothly, as well as hooking a couple of home laptops (Win-10 Professional) that access the Samba shares.
Everything runs OK. I see the shares, I can read/write, all golden.

Problem: when I transfer from WIN-10 onto the NAS (RAID) large amounts of files/data (i.e. a 5GB directory) Win-10 loses access to the shares on the NAS.   I restart samba [$ sudo service smbd restart] hit resume on win-10 explorer popup window, and the file transfer resumes and eventually the job gets done.

- in the end files are transferred correctly (although I have to restart samba several times)
- ssh connection to the server is never lost   (I monitor the server from one of the laptops)
- I've checked and RAID is not syncronzing, and all checks show green lights on the NAS
- also checked ext4lazyinit process an it's done its trick and all i-nodes have been created
- have already gone through a lot of forums, release notes, ... no trace of a similar issue
- NAS-TO-NAS disks transfers work OK, only laptop to NAS transfers are affected:
  USB-DISK ---[USB 3.0]---> WIN-10 LAPTOP ---[eth.cat5e]---> HP-PROLIANT SERVER   avg thpt =7MB/s

Has anyone had a similar issue ?

Comment: This is likely a Windows problem and not Ubuntu.  Any lines in the logfiles in `/var/log`?

Comment: could be... browsing around have found smthg about swappiness. Parameter was set at default [60] and I have tuned it down to 3 --> $ sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=3.   Now have just succeeded in making a 6GB xfer with just one samba crash.   It'd crashed several times with the previous setup.   Yet I can't figure out why samba keeps crashing at random.

Comment: as per the logs, no, I haven't looked into them yet; willdo soon.  Any suggestion abt what logs to look at first ?  (have plenty of them :)

Comment: syslog is the most likely. But as a rule of thumb: the one that are written last and the one that grows ;-)

Comment: Rinzwind tks for hint btw...  and why would you suggest a windows problem when it's samba crashing ?   Windows explorer copy window stays alive and allows me to resume copy after havin restarted samba....

Comment: The resume has likely nothing to do with it (that is an SCP/SSH feature). I work a lot with large files and even when the other end is not a Linux server Windows I tend to see a lot of dropped connection. And I also can not ignore that it is often around the 2.5Gb mark.

Comment: Rinzwind, I have been playing around this yesterday and found out that:
1) problem remains if I change windows client (i.e. try on a different laptop)
2) frequency of connection drops lowers considerably after setting vm.swappiness parameter to 10 (instead of the default 60) in Ubuntu

Comment: I am still stuck with the transfer problem.  Apparently lowering the swappiness parameter from 60 to 10 have reduced the frequency of the file transfer crashes, but they still happen.  File transfer isn't reliable, there must be some other issue around my installation.    Before the change from UBUNTU 15.xx  to UBUNTU 20.xx  my NAS was working like a charm...